# Mount Azure File share using cifs-utils and SAS Token

Tags: azure, mount, azure-storage-files

Is it possible to mount to Azure File share using mount.cifs and SAS token instead of Storage key? I tried this out but I got a Permission Denied, so I was wondering if this is possible.

```
sudo mount -t cifs //<storage account>.file.core.windows.net/<file share> <local path> -o vers=3.0,username=<storage account>,password="<sas token>",dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,serverino
```

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's impossible to do that. The SAS token is not supported in mounting Azure File share currently, it just supports the Azure storage account key. You can take a look at the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/14498352-allow-azure-files-shares-to-be-mounted-using-sas-s).

Comment: Officially not support, but you can do the trick like using [this](https://github.com/microsoft/AzureFilesFUSE).